# Adding a JSON type to a seeds file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2, mysql-8.0

```
Rails 5.2.3
MySQL 8 server with MySQL gem
```

My migration is working fine:

```
def change
  add_column :users, :roles, :json
end
```

The record was created in the users table as JSON. The problem I am having, is with the seeds file.

From the seeds file:

```
users = [
             {'email':"john@acme.net", 'first_name': "John", 'last_name': "Doe", 'status':'active', 'roles':"['admin']", 'password': "12345678", 'password_confirmation': "12345678"}
    ]
users.each do |user|
  User.create!(user) if User.find_by_email(user[:email]).nil?
end
```

When I run rake, I get the following error:

```
ActiveModel::RangeError: 1566947904332768 is out of range for ActiveModel::Type::Integer with limit 4 bytes
/db/seeds.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
/db/seeds.rb:8:in `each'
/db/seeds.rb:8:in `<main>'
/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/bin/spring:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I also tried:

```
'roles':['admin']
```

Same errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your some column either password or password confirmation needs to be upgraded to limit(16) or something in order to accept the characters that you are tryigin to save

```
    change_column :users, :password, :string, :limit => 55
    change_column :users, :password_confirmation, :string, :limit => 55
```

run a migration with this sentences and let us now if it works

Comment: No. Unless I need hard limits for some reason, the default string type is 256 characters, and password and password_confirmation are both string types. Note that they are contained within "", so they are not treated as integers.

Comment: In your table which attribute is integer type ?

Comment: I have no attributes of type integer

Comment: if you dont have any integer types in this column the only thing left would be that the id column it's full, do u have id's on this model ?

Comment: The problem was the audited gem. It was expecting the user_id to be an integer, and was taking the first few characters from the user_id, and trying to turn it into an integer. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700909/activerecord-thinks-im-using-an-integer-but-i-am-not